# Is it possible to use the version of PHP that is installed via brew in MAMP?

Tags: php, wordpress, development-environment, statamic

I have recently switched from Windows to Mac and would like some advice. I need to use a simple, flexible development environment for my projects. My projects are mainly based on Wordpress and Statamic.

According to the recommendation I tried MAMP. But before that I installed the PHP version via brew.

My question is. Is it possible to get the version of PHP that I already have installed on my Mac (using brew) into MAMP (free)?

***Follow-up question:***

Do you have any tips on what development environment to choose for PHP?

Comment: Laravel Valet, https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet is a fantastic dev enviroment for mac. Other good and modern alternative is https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sail Based on Docker. If you use develop in WordPress too, point directly to Valet.

Answer (score 0):

For me Laravel Valet (https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/valet) is the easiest way to get this setup on a Mac. Having used MAMP before, it has way some awesome features like exposing your local domain through ngrok or expose (from beyondco.de). It uses your PHP that you installed via brew and you can switch PHP versions too. And for managing valet and super easy access to restarting php, the php.ini and so on I can recommend PHP Monitor: https://github.com/nicoverbruggen/phpmon

You can add a self signed TLS certificate in a few seconds with Valet if needed.

Further I can't recommend DBngin enough for quickly setting up MYSQL (https://dbngin.com/). And for managing the SQL DBS: https://tableplus.com/.